# Click event that calls a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I am creating a Jasmine test to see if the function is being called when the object `$('#notification')` is clicked.

Here is the code from the `.cshtml` file:

```
$('#notification').click(function() {
    showNotification();
  });
```

Here is my current Jasmine test:

```
describe("Notification", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
       loadFixtures('dashboard.cshtml');
    });
    it("should call function when notification is clicked", function() {
       spyOn(window, 'showNotification');
       $('#notification').click();
       expect(window.showNotification).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

However, I'm getting this result:

```
Test 'Notification:should call function when notification is clicked' failed
    Expected spy showNotification to have been called.
```

Did i do it wrong? Am i missing something? I'm new to Jasmine.

EDIT: here's how the showNotification looks like.

```
function showNotification () { 
    loadNotification('', ''); 
    resetFields(); 
 }
```

EDIT: found a solution to my issue. i used the following code to simulate the click.

```
 $('#notification').on('click', function () {
           showNotification();
 });
 $('#notification').click();
```

i am now able to test if showNotification is being called and also the loadNotification and resetFields which are in showNotification.

thanks to those who responded. is there someone who will close this?

Comment: Make sure that `window.showNotification` exists and that function isn't nested inside another function.

Comment: Making sure it's not nested it's the biggie here - can you show the fixtures file? dashboard.cshtml

Comment: @DarrenSweeney im not sure im allowed show the code inside dashboard.cshtml but the showNotification looks something like this function showNotification () {
        loadNotifiction('', '');
        resetFields();
    }

Comment: Ok, not sure what you mean by allowed but if you need help you need to be able to provide all code related to the issue.

Comment: the Dashboard.cshtml is not actually a fixture file. it is a file that is being used in our project. am i approaching this wrong? should i create an actual fixture file?    

by allowed, i meant i might be breaking company rules if i were to share the whole cshtml file. and it is a big file that contains a lot of javascripts and objects.

Answer (score 0):

As the result says, you added the listener to the button, but never triggered it with click action.

Add this click action to trigger the test:

`$('#notification').trigger('click');`

Comment: do i put it after $('#notification').click(); ?

Comment: Please read OP. What do you think `$('#notification').click();` does?